Amazon Cognito with NLB
I saw a lot of threads to Amazon Cognito and ALB authentication, but is it also possible to use an NLB with Amazon Cognito?
I would expect to use Amazon Cognito with NLB, as I have issues with ALB and unreal pixel streaming (reconnects every 2 minutes)

No it is not possible. That isn't something supported by AWS at this time.
